# map.root does not work in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

- I have deleted public/index.html.
- Here is my config/routes.rb
- Those all I have in that file

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
    map.root :controller => "home"
- I've also tried using map.root :controller => "home#index"
- when I ran rake to check
  $ rake routes

  (in /var/www/atlantix)
        /:controller/:action/:id
        /:controller/:action/:id.:format 
     root  /                                {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
- I also have:

  app/views/home/index.html.erb
    app/controllers/home_controller.rb
- My issue:

I am a complete newbie of ROR.
I am using Apache and Ruby 1.8.
When I navigate to the http://localhost/myapp/,
I do not see the new home page I created.
Am I missnig something critical in my setup and configuration.
Please advise & help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmmm you seem to mix Rails 2 syntax. In Rails 3 you should write:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Note: you should also delete the `index.html` from the `public` folder.

More information concerning routing can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).